# The type must be convertible in case generic

Tags: c#, generics, bdd, specflow

My Test Project is built on BDD approach.
I was trying to call method through static variable. But something in my actions is wrong.

My code:

```
public class BasePage
{
    public T As<T>() where T : BasePage
    {
        return (T)this;
    }
}

public class PropertiesCollection
{
    private static BasePage _currentPage;

    public static BasePage currentPage
    {
        get { return _currentPage; }
        set
        {
            ScenarioContext.Current["class"] = value;
            _currentPage = ScenarioContext.Current.Get<BasePage>("class");
        }
    }
}
public sealed class LoginSteps
    {       
        [Given(@"I have navigated to my app")]
        public void GivenIHaveNavigatedToMyApp()
        {            Browser.Current.Navigate().GoToUrl(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["seleniumBaseUrl"]);
            PropertiesCollection.currentPage = new LoginPage();

        }
        [Given(@"I typed the (.*) and (.*)")]
        public void GivenITypedTheAnd(string username, string password)
        {
            var m = PropertiesCollection.currentPage.As<LoginPage>().Login(username, password);
        }
```

So in the last code line I has message error such as "The type must be convertible to ".Pages.BasePage" in order to use it as parameter  in the generic method ".Pages.BasePage.As()"
What should I change for fix it?

Comment: What's the definition of `LoginPage`? Does it extend `BasePage`?

Comment: Post LoginPage code too. Why do you need  private static BasePage _currentPage at all?

Comment: What is the point of `public T As<T>() where T : BasePage`? The usage would end up as `myBasePage.As<DerivedPage>()`, while `myObject as DerivedPage` is already available in C#... Furthermore, your version is a hard cast that throws exceptions, whereas the existing `as` implementation simply returns null.

Answer (score 0):

It's kind of impossible to understand your issue without full code but let me show you an example how it could be implemented.

```
public class Core
{
    protected CorePage CurrentPage
    {
        get
        {
            return ScenarioContext.Current.Get<CorePage>("CurrentPage";
        }
        set
        {
            ScenarioContext.Current["CurrentPage"] = value;
        }
    }

    public TPage InstanceOf<TPage>() where TPage : CorePage, new()
    {
        return new TPage();
    }

    public TPage As<TPage>() where TPage : CorePage
    {
        return (TPage) this;
    }
}

public class CorePage : Core
{
    //Base page class
}

public class HomePage : CorePage
{
    public void OpenLogin()
    {
        //Code 
        CurrentPage = new LoginPage();
    }
}

public class LoginPage : CorePage
{
    public void Something()
    {
        //Code
    }
}

[Binding]
public class Step : Core
{
    [Given(@"1st step")]
    public void BlaBlaBla1()
    {            
        CurrentPage.InstanceOf<HomePage>().OpenLogin();
    }

    [Then(@"2nd step")]
    public void BlaBlaBla2()
    {
        CurrentPage.As<LoginPage>().Something();
    }
}
```